Convert an optimization problem into box constraint
I recently read a statistics paper. It has an unconstrained problem:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||_1$$, where $$F(\theta)=L(\theta)+\frac{\rho}{2}|h(W(\theta))|^2+ \alpha h(W(\theta))$$
$\rho$ is a penalty parameter and $\alpha$ is a dual variable.
It uses the L-BFGS-B algorithm. It says the L-BFGS-B algorithm can be directly applied by casting the above problem into a box-constrained form:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||_1  \iff  \min_{\theta^+ \geq0, \theta^- \geq0} F(\theta^+-\theta^-)+\lambda \mathbf{1}^T (\theta^++\theta^-) $$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones.
My question is why this is equivalent?
My first observation is that  any real number x can be written as the difference of two non-negative numbers: $x = x^+ - x^-$, where $x^+ = \max(x,0)$ and $x^- = \max(-x,0)$, and we have $|x| = x^+ + x^-$. It looks like a proof.
The coding from that paper is
adj <- function(w) { # ?
w <- as.matrix(w)
w.pos <- w[1:(length(w)/2),]
w.neg <- w[((length(w)/2)+1):(length(w)),]
dim(w.pos) <- c(d,d)
dim(w.neg) <- c(d,d)
W <- w.pos - w.neg
return(W)}

But I notice that in the proof, one of $x^+$ and  $x^-$ must be $0$. But in the above coding, there's no such constraint. This is what I feel confused.

Your explanation for the transformation is correct.  Although there is no constraint that $x^+=0$ or $x^-=0$, it will happen naturally for every optimal solution because of the minimization objective.  Explicitly, any solution with both $x^+ > 0$ and $x^- > 0$ can be improved by subtracting $\min(x^+,x^-)$ from both.
